# Wrapper Function not working properly (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two functions: One the validates the information in name fields of a form, and another that takes the information in those fields and prints them out in an alert box. Separately these functions work fine. I have to call them both, so I created a wrapper function. The function runs, but it refreshes instead of focusing. The weird thing is, if I check the first field, everything is fine, including the .focus();, but when I try to validate the second field, .focus(); doesn't work and the page refreshes. Any help would be appreciated. (I tried to revise my first question to add this, but when I went to save it, nothing happend.)

```
function main() {
  var test = validate();
  if (test == true) {
    concatinate();
    return true;
  }
}

function validate() {
  //alert ("TEST!!!");
  var first = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
  if (first.length == 0 || first.length > 25) {
    alert("Please enter your first name, no longer than 25 chracters.");
    document.getElementById('firstname').focus();
    return false;
  }
  var last = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
  if (last.length == 0 || last.length > 25) {
    alert("Please enter your last name, no longer than 25 characters.");
    document.getElementsByName('lastname').focus();
    return false;
  }
  var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
  if (document.getElementById('title').selectedIndex == 0) {
    alert("Please select your salutation");
    document.getElementById('title').focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function concatinate() {
  var first = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
  var last = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
  var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
  var fullname = title + " " + first + " " + last;
  var printFull = "Welcome,  " + fullname;
  alert(printFull);
}

<form name="name" form id="name" method="post" onsubmit="return main();"> 
        Salutation: <select name="title" select id="title">
            <option selected="Please Select">Please select</option>
            <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        </select><br><br>
        First Name : <input type="text" input id="firstname" name="firstname">
        Last Name : <input type="text" input id="lastname" name="lastname"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: I know this isn't spelling class, but I think you were looking for "concatenate."

Comment: Clearly I've learned a lot in 4 years of college.

Comment: Where is that code in your HTML? Is it inside another function, `window.onload = function(){ ... }`, maybe?

Comment: The html is in it's own file. The js is external.

Comment: Hey Ty - I am confused as to what your ACTION IS. Are you POST'ing anywhere? The "return true" after your concatenate() func is probably the issue. Remove it. If you are not actually using the "POST" - remove that too. I think by default the page will refresh if no action is defined. Is this your intent?

Comment: Thank you for the info James! I took out the method and the return true. I was experimenting with different things trying to see if I could get the code to work properly, that why those are in there. The form actually isn't sending the information anywhere. This is all for an introduction to Js class. The assignment was to get it to validate the fields, and return the input in an alert box.

Comment: @TyGivens: Figured it out. Check out the update in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form, you have an erroneous attribute "form" in your `<form>`, "select" in the middle of the `<select>` tag, and "input" in the `<input>` tags. I'm not sure what they are there for, or whether they are causing you trouble, but you should get rid of them nonetheless.

Also, your problem is this line:

```
document.getElementsByName('lastname').focus();
```

`document.getElementsByName()` returns an array, and there is no `focus()` method on an array. This was causing your issue with validating the last name.

Change it to match your other `focus()` calls:

```
document.getElementById('lastname').focus();
```

I also removed the temporary variable in your `main()` method:

```
function main(form) {
    if (validate()) {
        concatinate();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cFsp5/4/**

Comment: I took them, out. Thank you for your input. I thought I was supposed to have those each time I used "id" or "name". I thought with out them, the "id" or "name" wouldn't work.

Comment: Guess we figured it out at the same time. +1

Comment: @Cory thank you so much! This has been bugging me for a few hours. This works perfectly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function **must** return `false` if validation doesn't pass. Otherwise, it will return `undefined`, and the form will submit anyway (which is what you describe). So a simple fix would be:

```
function main() {
  var test = validate();
  if (test == true) {
    concatinate();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LhXy4/

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will try to remember that. I think I actually had that at one point but I changed it since it wasn't working due to having "document.getElementsById" it was throwing everything off. But now I'll remember this rule.